# Not getting notification after manually removing RRO from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

For the purpose of learning, I've created a S3 bucket and uploaded couple of pics both in RRO(Reduced redundancy object mode) and standard. After that I created an SNS topic and I selected Email protocol for notification subscription then I got a subscription confirmation email and I confirmed the subscription. Later, I copied the Amazon resource name information(ARN) inside the notification section of S3 bucket.

Now, as per my understand if an object is lost with this RRS it should send a message to the SNS topic which in turn would drop information about the object which is lost to our email address.

But when I deleted the object from our bucket I didn't receive any notification.

Could someone please advise if I missed to understand something here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you misunderstand.  If *you* deleted a reduced-redundancy-storage object, the object was not "lost."

It's "lost" in the sense of "unexpectedly missing."

When S3 detects that an RRS object has **not** been intentionally deleted but also has no viable copies stored, that's when S3 has "lost" your object.

That's the only time you would see those messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearning the doubt. I've understood it now :)